Confused about question on universal property inverse limit
Context:
Let $S = \varprojlim S_{i}$ be a projective limit and define for each $j \in I$ the projection map $f_{j} : S \rightarrow S_{j}$ by $f_{j}((x_{i})_{i \in I}) = x_{j}$.
Now, I have already proven that the system $(S, (f_{j})_{j \in I})$ satisfies the universal property:

$f_{ij} \circ f_{i} = f_{j}$ for all $i, j \in I$ with $i \geq j$.

if $T$ is a set and $(g_{j} : T \rightarrow S_{j})_{j \in I}$ is a collection of maps satisfying $f_{ij} \circ g_{i} = g_{j}$ (for all $i, j \in I$ with $i \geq j$) then there is a unique $g : T \rightarrow S$ such that $g_{j} = f_{j} \circ g$ for all $j \in I$.


Question: I have to prove that this universal property characterizes $(S, (f_{j})_{j \in I})$ in the following way: if $S'$ is a set and $(f'_{j} : S' \rightarrow S_{j})_{j \in I}$ is a collection of maps satisfying the analogues of 1 and 2, then there is a unique bijection $f' : S' \rightarrow S$ such that $f'_{j} = f_{j} \circ f'$ for all $j \in I$.
Here I am a bit confused. This is because initially I thought about applying property (2) with $T = S'$ to find a unique map $f' : S' \rightarrow S$ such that $f'_{j} = f_{j} \circ f'$ for all $j \in I$, but I am not sure how to proceed since I would want to apply property (2) again with $T = S$ to find a unique map $f'' : S \rightarrow S'$, but I don't think that is possible since it is not said that $S'$ itself is a projective limit.
If anybody could help me out I would appreciate that.

You don't need that $S'$ is a projective limit, the assumption is that $S'$ satisfies properties analogous to (1) and (2), so in particular, you can apply property (2) to $S'$ for $T=S$.

Thank you for your comment @Albert. Is this the right approach? We obtain a $f' : S' \rightarrow S$ such that $f_{j}' = f_{j} \circ f'$ and we obtain a $f'' : S \rightarrow S'$ such that $f_{j} = f_{j}' \circ f''$. This gives that $f_{j} = f_{j} \circ f' \circ f''$, and hence $f' \circ f'' = \text{id}{S}$. Similarly, we get that $f{j}' = f_{j}' \circ f'' \circ f'$ and thus $f'' \circ f' = \text{id}_{S'}$. So they are each other's inverse and thus $f'$ is a bijection between $S'$ and $S$.

yes, that's it! Maybe, just to add something, the fact that &f'\circ f''$ and $f''\circ f'$ are the identities follows from the uniqueness in the universal property. But I think you already notice that :-)
